# Expected value of sum squared is sum of expected value squared?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, summation

Consider the following expression:

$ X \sim BIN(1, p) $

$ Var(\bar{X})=Var(\frac{\sum_i{X_i}}{n}) = \frac{1}{n^2} Var(\sum_i X_i) = \frac{1}{n^2} \left( \sum_i E(X_i^2) - ( \sum_i E(X_i) )^2 \right) $

$ = \frac{1}{n^2} \left( \sum_i (pq+p^2) - (np)^2 \right) = \frac{1}{n^2} (npq+np^2 -n^2p^2) = \frac{np(1-p)}{n} $

Now I know that the C.R.L.B. is equal to this: $ Var(T) \geq \frac{p(1-p)}{n} $

This means that I must get the same expression to show that $ \bar{X} $ is the UMVUE.

Clearly my expression has a $n$ which shouldn't be there. I think my mistake is in this part:

$ \ \   E(\sum_i X_i)^2 = \left(  \sum_i E(X_i) \right)^2 = (np)^2 = n^2p^2  $

So I think it should be:

$ \ \   E(\sum_i X_i)^2 =  \sum_i \left( E(X_i)^2 \right) = np^2  $

Because that does yield the correct answer.

So is this indeed the mistake or did I make another mistake?
And I would also greatly appreciate it if someone could explain **why** this is wrong because I don't get the reasoning behind it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$E(\sum_i X_i)^2 $ is ambiguous: it could be $\left(E(\sum_i X_i)\right)^2$ or  $E\left((\sum_i X_i)^2\right)$

For a binomial distribution (the sum of $n$ independent Bernoulli random variables), the former is $n^2p^2$ (the square of the mean), while the latter is $np(1-p) + n^2p^2$ (the variance plus the square of the mean).

In your expression, you could have

$ Var(\bar{X})=Var(\frac{\sum_i{X_i}}{n}) = \frac{1}{n^2} Var(\sum_i X_i) =  \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_i Var( X_i) =  \frac{np(1-p)}{n^2}=  \frac{p(1-p)}{n}$

or

$ Var(\bar{X})=Var(\frac{\sum_i{X_i}}{n}) = \frac{1}{n^2} Var(\sum_i X_i) = \frac{1}{n^2} \left( E\left((\sum_i X_i)^2\right) - \left(E(\sum_i X_i)\right)^2 \right) $

Comment: Don't I have to deal with covariance if I take the $Var$ of a sum? I thought $Var(\sum_i X_i) = \sum_i Var(X_i)$ wasn't allowed.

Comment: Ow I see it now. Because the variables are independently distributed (not in the question but I think I can assume this), I can follow your line of thought. Just like explained in this post: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31177/does-the-variance-of-a-sum-equal-the-sum-of-the-variances.

Alright thank you!